# Shows not returned by getfavorites API Call

Tags: sonos

I'm using [getfavorites](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/favorites/getfavorites/) to retrieve a list of Favorites.
It shows all my songs, playlists etc, but does not return my "Shows".

Is there any reason for excluding "Shows"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The My Sonos tab (which includes “Shows”) in the Sonos app is a superset of favorites and playlist. That is, it contains items that are not retrievable at this time with the `getFavorites` and `getPlaylists` commands. Shows are amongst these items. I’ll let the dev team know that you’d like access to these items as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Yes that would be great, as it is currently confusing that those show up in Sonos Favorites, but are not returned by getFavorites.

Comment: Just to be clear, they show up in My Sonos, which as I mentioned is a superset of Favorites and Playlists.